# SQL Server maintenance tasks cannot run after changing computer name

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I am having a problem performing maintenance tasks on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 after changing my server name from the original random name given during installation to the one I prefer

This is the error am getting

> *Could not obtain Information about Windows NT group/users
>   'WIN-4N4A9TLBGJJ\Administrator', error code 0x534*

Is there a way I can fix this problem without having to delete the account and recreating it again?

Answer (score 1):

Did you execute sp_dropserver and sp_addserver? If not, you need to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799(v=sql.100).aspx